# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error at createError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm going to use Axios to communicate API.
But that kind of error keeps coming out. I don't understand this problem. I searched on the Internet and tried everything. Help me.
All I want is to click on that button to see the low value in the developer tool.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setJwt(getClientCookieFromClient('jwt'));
  }, []);

  const customFetch = async () => {
    const res = await axios
      .get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WECODE_URI}/subscription/master_table`, {
        headers: {
          Authentication: jwt,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => res.data);
    if (!res.data.success) {
      alert(res.data.message);
    }
  };

...

<button onClick={() => customFetch()}>API호출버튼</button>
```

Comment: After the `.then` line, add `.catch(e) {console.error(e)}`.  That will handle the error by logging it, and it will hopefully give some more detail about what the problem is.

Comment: remove ".then((res) => res.data);", that part is assigning "data" to "res", which is making your if statement fail.

Comment: @user2740650 The syntax is `.catch(e => console.error(e))`

Answer (score 0):

##### Note:

not sure about you response structure. Current code works as expected for structure:

```
res = { data: { data: {success: true}}}
```

if it is not so, then use `if` statement as `!res.success`

---

```
useEffect(() => {
    setJwt(getClientCookieFromClient('jwt'));
  }, []);

  const customFetch = async () => {
    const res = await axios
      .get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WECODE_URI}/subscription/master_table`, {
        headers: {
          Authentication: jwt,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error while fetching",err)); //<--- use .catch for catching error
    if (!res.data.success) {
      alert(res.data.message);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Alway wrap await inside try/catch block.

```
const customFetch = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios
      .get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WECODE_URI}/subscription/master_table`, {
        headers: {
          Authentication: jwt,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => res.data);
    if (!res.data.success) {
      alert(res.data.message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // Do something with error
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
useEffect(() => {
  setJwt(getClientCookieFromClient('jwt'));
}, []);

const customFetch = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WECODE_URI}/subscription/master_table`, {
    headers: {
      Authentication: jwt,
    },
  });
  if (!res.data.success) {
    alert(res.data.message);
  }
};
```